# Flash vs HTML5 game development for web & mobile

Tags: javascript, flash, html, mobile

I am an experienced AS3 programmer, and I've done Flash apps and games on the browser and on mobile (via Adobe AIR, e.g., on Android).

I am about to start developing a game (basic 2D platformer with pixelart graphics. Think about Super Mario World) targeted to both web and mobile platforms. **Thus I'm searching for easy deployment to these two kinds of platforms, having basically the same source code.**

I'm divided between choosing ActionScript 3.0 (Flash) or HTML5/JavaScript for developing this game.

My main question is, for those who've experienced the same situation before:

### What is the safest way to go?

In other words, are there serious disadvantages with one of these frameworks that **disallows** me to develop multiplatform 2D games?

Or am I just dreaming and practical multiplatform (web and mobile) game development is not so possible? (does someone know how Rovio did it with Angry Birds?)

---

Here are some pros and cons that I already know:

Pros for AS3/Flash:

- The state-of-art for web games.
- I'm experienced with it.
- (Almost) concealed source code.
- On the web, it's browser-independent.
- Can run as a "native" app on iOS and Android through Adobe AIR. It's not the best performance experience ever, but I know that you can get *playable* performances with it.

Cons for AS3/ Flash:

- Performance on AIR for mobile is not optimal, so I might end up having to abandon a really cool but expensive feature (or even several features).
- People are saying HTML5/Javascript will substitute it.

Pros for HTML5/Javascript:

- It's possible to do Flash-quality games using, e.g., engines like [ImpactJS](http://www.impactjs.com) or Akihabara.
- Seems to be more stable and well supported on mobile in the future.
- Deployment as native app is possible through [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/), appMobi, etc.

Cons for HTML5/Javascript:

- I have some basic knowledge of this technology.
- Source code is wide open exposed.
- Performance/behaviour is browser-dependent.
- Lacks a solid framework or engine which is free of co$t$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Angry Birds got ported when it went from mobile game to the web.  Something like PhoneGap might be your best option (as far as I know, it's free)

Comment: Angry Birds for the web was developed using Google's ForPlay and GWT: http://www.quora.com/Angry-Birds-game/How-did-Rovio-build-its-Google-Chrome-version-of-Angry-Birds (so it is not the same source as for example the native iOS app).

Comment: Wouldn't another plus for Flash be the much wider market you'd be able to reach, with IE6-8 support?

Comment: Indeed the biggest minus for HTML5 right now is that you'd lose the majority of desktop Internet users. It's great as a future technology and I am about to start exploring it deeply at work.

Comment: Oh and this plus for Flash is extremely dangerous: (Almost) concealed source code. You should always treat AS3 as open-source (ie. design your applications the same way you would using JavaScript) because it is trivially easy to decompile.

Comment: I think code obfusctation for AS3 is more advanced and effective than obfuscation for Javascript, that's why I said almost concealed source code.
By the way, thanks Lars for the ForPlay link, this is definitely a good alternative worth at least taking a look (if Rovio did it, why couldn't others...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've decided to forget about HTML5 for cross-platform game development, and specially for deployment to mobile.

The cons I've pointed out for Flash are much lighter than the cons for HTML5. Basically, for the pixelart kind of games, **Flash on mobile performs really well, specially if using some nice engine like Flixel**.

For example, the Flixel game *Robo Run* has great performance both on [Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=air.de.codinsoft.littleRoboRun&hl=en) and [Flash Player in a browser](http://www.flixelgames.net/robo-run/). I don't have an iOS example for the same game, but I believe it would perform as good as on Android.

Plus, Flash performance on mobile shouldn't be an increasing problem since the hardware on these devices just gets better and better.

After thinking about this HTML5 vs Flash issue for several months, I think there's no point adventuring in HTML5 cross-browser compatibility since Flash has proven to be a sort of Java for 2D games.

Comment: Well - by waiting almost a year to make up your mind, you also get the benefit that flash now exports with OpenGL to iOS and Android. I can finally give flash for mobile apps my blessing.

Comment: Yes, http://gaming.adobe.com/ is the answer we were expecting.

Comment: Its 2016 - are those conclusions still true? I want to leverage the JS ecosystem which would be hard/impossible in as3

Answer (score 2):

I think you have outlined the pros and cons pretty effectively. If cross platform and mobile web development is your *top* priority, Flash is a good choice. You will have all of the drawbacks you have identified.

If you use javascript/HTML such as the impact engine, you will have a different set of problems, and far less compatibilty on the web side.

However, if having the game be the best it can be, you will need to look elsewhere, because as of the present, there is no code once publish anywhere solution.

Unity 3D has good 3D and 2d mobile capabilities.
Appcellerator may also be your cup of tea.
http://www.appcelerator.com/

But in the final analysis, nothing will beat making different versions for different platforms. in terms of performance, and being best suited to the device. Be sure to evaluate how well your chosen solution allows you to monetize your app as well. You'll likely be building multiple versions just to accomodate differences in revenue models and ad serving capabilities.

=== Update ===
In March of 2012 Adobe updated flash for iOS and Android to include support for OpenGL graphics, 3D and 2D graphics are now possible using flash as a single code base for iOS and Android. The speed is good, and you also can deply the same game to web. Its a great tool. The one drawback is that flash relies on "extensions" to connect to native OS capabilites such as Intents on android or Game Center on iOS. If you plan on using native capabilities extensively, look out for this as an obstacle to development.

Answer (score 1):

As ScanPlayGames said, html5 sound is a big issue.  There are some neat WebGL ports though.  Dominic at Impact has been doing some amazing stuff.  He's got the best framework out there.

Rovio did a port using Google Web Toolkit for the chrome store.

I work for AppMobi.  We've got a tool called DirectCanvas for iOS (Android will be coming soon) that increases the performance of games in the webview.  One of our partners is developing a game that has the concept of Angry Birds (object A is propelled to destroy other objects).  So Box2d support is there (the main thing holding us up from releasing).  The performance is awesome, and the average joe doesn't know it's a webview game.

And trust me, you wont' be wasting your time doing development on mobile first for desktop then.  We've got some stuff up our sleeves.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Flash games developer too and did some research on how to migrate to HTML5. There are a lot of obstacles if you come from the Flash/ActionScript3 world. One of those things is JavaScript itself - i know many people like JavaScript, but if you are used to AS3 it is hard. Another thing is the problem with sounds (as mentioned above). The most important thing is that i don't want to start from scratch and i want to use my skills or even migrate code from the past.

To make a long story short i ended up with Googles new programming language called Dart. This language compiles to JavaScript in therefore runs on all modern browsers. The most important thing is that Dart is very similar to ActiontScript3! Then i did an open source library which provides all the Flash API you need for games (The Display List, Bitmaps, Sounds, ...) - i tried to make the library as compatible as possible with the Flash API to simplify the process of porting the source of a game. In the end it was pretty easy because you only need to change a few things.

The [game](http://www.dartflash.com/games/escape/escape.html) i have migrated: 
An [ActionScript](http://www.dartflash.com/docs/actionscript-dart.html) to Dart comparison: 
Some other samples and the [link](http://www.dartflash.com) to the source:

Answer (score 1):

I think a big disadvantage of Javascript is that it cannot detect picture's transparent regions so that it can stop reacting while mice hover or click on it.
Since HTML5 was released, any new solution has been created?

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with some people who did a very graphics intensive HTML5 application and the worst thing was doing the sound I remember...every browser had to be done differently. Go look for some open source html 5 game frameworks where people have already done the grunt work of testing across browsers...there are some pretty good ones I think. You dont want to have to be the one QA-ing across environments.